# Abrir pagina desde html dependiendo de if statement

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

estoy creando una página web donde se podrán crear dos tipos de usuarios, A y B. Para ello tengo un script donde la gente puede decidir que tipo de cuenta usar. Cada cuenta re-dirige a una u otra pero no sé como se puede hacer desde un script. Aquí tengo el código:

```
<h2> Crear cuenta </h2>

<select name="cuenta" id="tipo" >
   <option selected value="0"> Tipo de cuenta </option> 
       <option valor="A">A</option> 
       <option valor="B">B</option> 
 </select>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>

    function elegir(){

        a = document.getElementById("tipo");        
        if(a.value == "A")           

           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A";

        else if (a.value == "B")

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "B";

        }

 </script>
 <button onclick="elegir()">Crear</button>
```

Ahora mismo lo que hace es imprimir A o B según la elección, me gustaría que no mostrase eso sino que fuese ahí cuando re-dirige a un sitio u otro. ¿Sería posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para dirigir al usuario a un sitio u otro, la función javascript [location.assign](http://devdocs.io/dom/location/assign) o sea que el código te quedaría:

```
if (a.value == "A") {
  document.location.assign('/user/A')
} else if (a.value == "B") {
  document.location.assign('/user/B')
}
```

Igualmente, si lo que querés es dar opciones sobre a qué página ir, lo recomendable es usar simplemente enlaces:

```
<p>Seleccione su tipo de usuario</p>
<a href="/user/A">Anónimo</a>
<a href="/user/B">Beta user</a>
```

De esa manera no necesitas ningún javascript

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil de hacer con Jquery, aquí te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="cuenta" id="tipo">
        <option selected value="0"> Tipo de cuenta </option>
        <option valor="A">A</option>
        <option valor="B">B</option>
    </select>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function elegir() {
            var valor = $('#tipo').val();
            if (valor == "A") {
                window.location.href = "/web1.php";
            } else if (valor == "B") {
                window.location.href = "/web2.php";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="elegir()">Crear</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Aquí lo ves en ejecución:

```js
function elegir(){
      var valor = $('#tipo').val();
      if (valor == "A") {
        location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com";
      }
      else if (valor == "B"){
        location.href = "https://google.com.co";
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cuenta" id="tipo" >
         <option selected value="0"> Tipo de cuenta </option> 
         <option valor="A">A</option> 
         <option valor="B">B</option> 
</select>
<button onclick="elegir()">Crear</button>
```

> Ojo
>   Puedes usar:

- `window.location.href` - para ir a una pestaña dentro de tu web.
- `location.href` - para ir a una url distinta.

Answer (score 0):

hola sugiero hacer este proceso desde php y sql
almacenando las cuentas tipo a y b

```
<select name="cuenta" id="tipo" >
   <option selected value="0"> Tipo de cuenta </option> 
       <option valor="A">A</option> 
       <option valor="B">B</option> 
</select>
    <?php
$cuenta=$_POST['cuenta']
if($cuenta === a) {
    header('location:cuenta_a.php');
}
if($cuenta === b) {
    header('location:cuenta_b.php');
}
?>
```

cuentanos como te fue

Answer (score 0):

modifica tu select para que en cada opcion contenga el enlace al cual se debe dirigir al usuario segun el tipo de cuenta, de la siguiente forma :

```
<select name="cuenta" id="tipo" onchange="location = this.value;">
   <option selected='' value="0"> Tipo de cuenta </option> 
       <option value="/user/A">A</option> 
       <option value="/user/B">B</option> 
</select>
```

asi no necesitas usar javascript.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya cambié el select y puse el link al que quiero redirigirme pero soy un poco nuevo así que ahora no se que hacer con eso. Al elegir una opción no se dirige directamente a la página y el botón que tenía antes ya no sirve para esto. ¿Qué debería hacer?

Comment: hice una actualizacion, asegurate de poner en el value de cada option la url a donde quieres redigir, si deseas no hacer nada para la primera option puedes poner en el atributo onclick lo siguiente if (this.value != '') location = this.value;

Comment: attributo onchange no onclick disculpa